# I've tried almost everything I could find off the web. Nothing. Is there any way to merge a string and a variable, to open a program in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm a bit experienced in batch, but not that much. Just a bit past beginner. I have a program I am trying to open, using batch. The problem is, if someone else is going to use this, how will I be able to get the directory of the program I'm trying to open, if it is a different username, than what the path has, and I don't know their username. I fixed that by getting the file by using %CD%. How will I merge the variable %CD%, with a string, which is the rest of the path, into a command that will open the program using these two. So, the %CD%, which is the first part of the path (a variable) and the string (the second part of the path)?

**My Code**

```
@ECHO OFF
set mypath=%cd%

:top
set /P c=Welcome to Hentai Virus. Enter [help] to get a list of commands:
if /I "%c%" EQU "help" goto :enter_help
if /I "%c%" EQU "gui" goto :enter_gui
if /I "%c%" EQU "hentai virus" goto :virus_start
goto :top

:under
set /p r=
if /I "%r%" EQU "help" goto :enter_help
if /I "%r%" EQU "gui" goto :enter_gui
if /I "%r%" EQU "hentai virus" goto :virus_start
goto :under


:enter_help

echo Commands
echo --------
echo - help
echo shows you all the commands and uses that this command-line can do.
echo -
echo - gui
echo opens the gui. Much better and easier than a dumb command line-tool.
echo -
echo - hentai virus
echo starts the virus and unleashes what can be found at the dephs of hell. Basically all hell on "a" computer.
goto :under

:enter_gui
echo ---------------------------------
echo Sorry, not currently made yet.
echo ---------------------------------
goto :under

:virus_start
this isnt working. Is there any way to merge a variable and a string to open a program?
```

Comment: Edit: This isn't a real virus. Just an annoying website spammer

Comment: That's a lot of code totally unrelated to your problem. Show us, what you tried *to solve your problem* (the rest just convinces us of your bad intentions. Unlikely we want to be part of them)

Comment: You've posted a lot of code right up until the code you need help with, then not told us what that code is. All we know is that you're trying to merge a variable and a string, but we don't know which variable, I'm assuming `%mypath%`, as that is the only useful one you've defined, or which string. Could you please [edit] your question, to include the actual command you're trying to run, under the `:hentai_virus` label. Please ensure that you show us how the variable you're using, if it is not `%mypath%`, was defined, any debugging information, and what happens contrary to your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `cd C:%homepath%` that will change directory to: C:/users/username. I think that will help

Comment: Better use `cd /D %HOME%`, because `HOME` contains the full path with the drive letter and  `cd /D` is able to change the drive too

Comment: Didn't know that before, nice.

Comment: This is one way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SET command to see the value of all variables. Here are a few.

```
 8:45:49.39  C:\Users\lit>SET
...
HOMEDRIVE=H:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\example.com\dfs1\home\lit
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\lit\AppData\Local
...
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
...
TEMP=C:\Users\lit\AppData\Local\Temp
...
USERNAME=lit
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\lit
windir=C:\windows
```

I suggest using `CD /D "%USERPROFILE%"` or `CD "%CD%\thedir"`.

Comment: Set doesnt work in the latest version of VBS, but thank you anyways.

Comment: `SET` is a cmd.exe command to display environment variables and their values. it has nothing to do with VBS. You are writing a .bat file script. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of your script, with some improvements:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "BasePath=%~dp0"

Echo Welcome to Hentai Virus.

:Top
Set "message=To get a list of commands, enter help"

:Under
Set "c="
Set /P "c=%message%>"
If Not Defined c If Not Defined message (GoTo Under) Else GoTo Top
Set "c=%c:"=%"
(Set c) 2>NUL | "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /R /I /C:"c=help" /C:"gui" ^
 /C:"hentai virus" 1>NUL || GoTo Top
If /I "%c%" == "help" GoTo Enter_Help
If /I "%c%" == "gui" GoTo Enter_GUI
If /I "%c%" == "hentai virus" GoTo Virus_Start

:Enter_Help
Set "message="
Echo Commands
Echo --------
Echo   help           Shows you all the supported commands and their uses.
Echo(
Echo   gui            Opens the GUI.
Echo                  Much better and easier than a dumb command line-tool.
Echo(
Echo   hentai virus   Starts the virus and unleashes what can be found at the^
 depths
Echo                  of hell. Basically all hell on "a" computer.
GoTo Under

:Enter_GUI
Echo ---------------------------------
Echo Sorry, not currently made yet.
Echo ---------------------------------
GoTo Under

:Virus_Start
Echo=Start "" "%BasePath%HentaiVirus.exe" & Pause
```

At the bottom line its `Echo`ing the command which would be run, *(without `Echo=` prepended)*. That obviously includes an answer to your question, i.e. a variable, merged with a made up string `HentaiVirus.exe`. The only real difference is that I used the path of the running script, `%~dp0`, whereas you used `%cd%`, for the current working directory, *(which is unknown)*. If you have a specific known path for your 'pretend' virus, replace `%~dp0` with the full path of the parent directory for that executable file, and make sure that you include a trailing backward slash, e.g. `Set "BasePath=%UserProfile%\Downloads\"`. When you're satisfied that the last line is correct, just remove `Echo=`, and  `& Pause` from it, and on its next run, it should work as intended.

Comment: Your answer didn't really fix my problem. Instead made it easier. I thank you for all your work on redesigning my script, so I will take your answer as the finishing answer. I'm going to use some other coding language to do this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Please note @crjase, from my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704248/ive-tried-almost-everything-i-could-find-off-the-web-nothing-is-there-any-way/66714864#comment117932450_66704248), that you did not define a problem, you just told us you had one. I created this as a guess, and because it is a correct way to structure your code. This site expects a [mcve] of your issue, in order that we can replicate it ourselves. Please read [ask] and each of its linked pages, in order to learn what the expectations are, and how to better use this site.

Comment: Sorry. I'm horrible at doing this kind of stuff. I never give enough detail, I always ask obvious questions, I'm just bad at this. I will read on how to properly ask questions. Thank you for everything, really.